# Why is it so hard to find the amount of biotin in food?

Tags: nutrition, health

According to the [WHO publications](http://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/10665/42716/1/9241546123.pdf?ua=1) biotin is a thing we need. Although its non toxic, so you can't get too much.

However, excluding a few (small) lists that deal exclusively with biotin content there doesn't generally seem to be any information on how much of it given foods contain. For instance this page gives a very impressive [summary of a kiwi](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/fruits-and-fruit-juices/1934/2), but there is no mention of biotin.

If this is something we need, why is it not normally listed?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Biology Stack exchange. Unfortunately this seems to be a primarily opinion based question and won't result in good quality answers.

Comment: Biotin is also called vitamin H or vitamin B7. You might try searching for those.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's really hard to measure biotin levels in food accurately.

From "[Determination of the biotin content of select foods using accurate
and sensitive HPLC/avidin binding](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1450323/pdf/nihms-9393.pdf)" (2004, emphasis added):

> Total biotin content of 87 foods was determined using acid
>   hydrolysis and the HPLC/avidin-binding assay. These values are consistent with published values
>   in that meat, fish, poultry, egg, dairy, and some vegetables are relatively rich sources of biotin.
>   However, these biotin values disagreed substantially with published values for many foods. Assay
>   values varied between 247 times greater than published values for a given food to as much as 36%
>   less than the published biotin value. Among 51 foods assayed for which published values were
>   available, only seven agreed within analytical variability (720%). **We conclude that published values
>   for biotin content of foods are likely to be inaccurate.**